# Limit the number of posts from Facebook API

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the following code for fetching posts from facebook.

```
dynamic feed = _facebookClient.Get(string.Format(appURL));
```

Is there any way to limit the number of posts i get in return? This method returns 25+ posts, which takes 2-4 seconds.

I've tried finding an answer from [the documentation](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/) without any luck.

Comment: What contains `string.Format(appURL)`?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert It contains the facebook app url. ["FacebookAppURL"];

Comment: Can I get a print of this `string`?

Comment: var appURL = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppURL"];

Comment: I'm asking you to **print** this var. What does this var **contain**? Probably not `FacebookAppURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `string.Format(appURL)` contains a Graph API request `USER_ID/feed`, we can add a field that specify the limit:

```
dynamic feed = _facebookClient.Get(string.Format(appURL) + "?limit=10");
```

You will find more information about `LIMIT` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/).

Comment: Hi! I'm still getting 25 items from the feed, after adding LIMIT = 10

Comment: Very nice! It works. How about skipping items? Using infinite scroll, and i would like to skip already added items. does ?skip=5 exist?

Comment: Yes, use `offset` instead of `skip`. Read the doc.